# FragmentPagerAdapter getItem is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am not able to reuse fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter.. Using destroyItem() method, It is deleting the fragment but still does not called getItem() again..There are just 2-3 Images so I am using FragmentPagerAdapter Instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter..

```
public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList < String > urls;
    int size = 0;
    public ExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList < String > res) {
        super(fm);
        urls = res;
        size = urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (urls == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return size;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment) object);
        trans.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = new FloorPlanFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("p", position);
        b.putString("image", urls.get(position));
        Log.i("image", "" + urls.get(position));
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

And In FragmentActivity,

```
pager.setAdapter(new ExamplePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), res2));
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you overrode `destroyItem()`? That is not necessary.

Comment: to initialize again use FragmentStatePagerAdapter

also call when you override it
super.destroyItem(container, position, object);

Answer (score 317, accepted):

KISS Answer:

Simple use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html).

I got the answer.. Firstly I thought to delete this question as I am doing a very silly mistake but this answer will help someone who is facing the same problem that Instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

As @BlackHatSamurai mentioned in the comment:

> The reason this works is because `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` destroys
>   as Fragments that aren't being used. `FragmentPagerAdapter` does not.

Comment: Hate to be another 'me too!' post, but yeah >.< Thanks for not deleting the question.

Comment: My guess would be something along the lines of the fragments getting dumped into a recycling bin for later use when destroyed, so that when a new pager gets created, it gets filled with recycled fragments. Could probably also be fixed by not putting any content specific code in the getItem call (such as setting an image based on the pagers variables, arrays ect...)

Comment: The reason this works is because FragmentStatePagerAdapter destroys as Fragments that aren't being used. FragmentPagerAdapter does not.

Comment: @Blaine thanks, you cleared my mind. Btw, thank you bro, you saved me from a big problem.

Comment: Just for future reference for those who may find this while searching for a specific problem they're having; read up on both FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter.  They behave differently for a reason and your specific use might require one over the other.

Comment: @najibputhawala I used FragmentStatePagerAdapter but still facing same issue. getItem() not called

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually Everyone did a silly mistake :D

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, you saved me a lot of time. +1

Comment: @Kanika what is a kiss answer?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer spent almost 2hrs debugging, trying different things.

Comment: I have this problme even with you solution.

Answer (score 173):

Using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` didn't fully fix my problem which was a similar issue where `onCreateView` was not being called for child fragments in the view pager. I am actually **nesting my `FragmentPagerAdapter` inside of another `Fragment`** therefore the `FragmentManager` was shared throughout all of them and thus retaining instances of the old fragments. The fix was to instead feed an instance of the `getChildFragmentManager` to the constructor of the `FragmentPagerAdapter` in my host fragment. Something like...

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

The `getChildFragmentManager()` method is accessible via a fragment and this worked for me because it returns a private `FragmentManager` for that fragment specifically for situations in which nesting fragments is needed.

- Keep in mind however to use `getChildFragmentManager()` your minimum API version must be atleast `17 (4.2)`, so this may throw a wrench in your gears. Of course, if you are using fragments from the support library v4 you should be okay.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problem is due that the fragments nested in other fragments should use getChildrenFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().

Comment: I same case of nested fragment i still have problem. In my case my last items ( for example 9,10) getItem not called! it is very odd.

Comment: does not work for me because this: 
adapter = new MyAdapter( ChildFragmentManager );
will cause: 
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager'

Answer (score 9):

**Override `long getItemId (int position)`**

`FragmentPagerAdapter` caches the fragments it creates using `getItem`. I was facing the same issue- even after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` `getItem` was not being called.

This is actually a feature and not a bug. You need to override `getItemId` so that you can correctly reuse your fragments. Since you are removing fragments, your positions are changing. As mentioned in the docs:

> `long getItemId (int position)`
>
> Return a unique identifier for the item at the given position.
>
> The default implementation returns the given position. **Subclasses should override this method if the positions of items can change.**

Just provide a unique id to each fragment and you're done.

Using a `FragementStatePagerAdapter` or returning `POSITION_NONE` in `int getItemPosition (Object object)` is wrong. You will not get any caching.

Comment: This one was the correct answer. I had to provide different ids for the fragments in `getItemId` AND adjust `getItemPosition` to return `POSITION_NONE` IF the fragment should be removed. I have a enum flag for that. After that `getItem` will be called.

Comment: Thank you @MuratKaragöz for the +50 :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works better with this method overrided.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me too. It's only working solution for me after trying everything.

Answer (score 5):

I did what @kanika and @Jraco11 had posted but I still had the problem.

So, after a lot of changes, I found one that worked for me and was added to my FragmentPagerAdapter the next code:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

According to what I read, **getItemPosition** is used to notify the **ViewPager** whether or not to refresh an item, and to avoid updates if the items at the visible positions haven't changed.

Answer (score 4):

method `getItem()` is used only to create new items. Once they created, this method will not be called. If you need to get item that is currently in use by adapter, use this method:

```
pagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, TAB_POS)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two different scenarios :
1.) You have same layout for every pager :
        In that case, it will be better if you'll extend your custom adapter
        by PagerAdapter and return a single layout.

2.) You have different layout for every pager :
        In that case, it will be better if you'll extend your custom adapter
        by FragmentStatePagerAdapter and return different fragmets for every pager.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting a listener on the tab-layout stopped this from being called, probably because they only have space for one listener on `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener` instead of an array of listeners.