# page viewer in Fragment gives black window in android

Tags: android, gridview, mobile, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

In my application i am using navigation drawer.In one fragment of drawer i have one page viewer with 3 child's.In the initial working viewpager works perfectly.But when i reload the pageviewer it gives below screen.

[image]

In initial run i got,

[image]

The following are the codes i used

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


MyAdapter mAdapter;
Context mContext;
ViewPager mViewPager;
AuthorFragment galleryActivity;
Button author,mostRead,a2Z;
int Width;
public HomeFragment(){}

public HomeFragment(Context c)
{
    this.mContext=c;        
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.pager);    
    author = (Button)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.author_id);   
    mostRead = (Button)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.most_read_id);  
    a2Z = (Button)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.az_id);  


}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager(), galleryActivity);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView. findViewById(R.id.pager);
    author = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.author_id); 
    mostRead = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.most_read_id);    
    a2Z = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.az_id);    

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    click(a2Z,2);
    click(mostRead,1);
    click(author,0);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();  
    author.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width/3,Width/9));
    mostRead.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width/3,Width/9));
    a2Z.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width/3,Width/9));


    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(arg0 == 0){
                author.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pagetitle);
                mostRead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_strip_selector);
                a2Z.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_strip_selector);  
            }
            else if (arg0 == 1) {
                author.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_strip_selector);
                mostRead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pagetitle);
                a2Z.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_strip_selector);
            }
            else {
                author.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_strip_selector);
                mostRead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_strip_selector);
                a2Z.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pagetitle);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}


public  class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    AuthorFragment gallery;
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, AuthorFragment gallery) {
        this(fm);
        this.gallery = gallery;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            return new MostReadFragment(mContext);

        case 1:

            return new MostReadFragment(mContext);
        case 2:
            return new A2ZFragment(mContext);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

}


}
```

The content of pageViewer is a gridview

```
public class AuthorFragment extends Fragment {
BookListAdapter adapter;
GridView bookGrid;
Context mContext;
ArrayList<Book> bookList=new ArrayList<Book>();
BookListParser ListParser=new BookListParser(); 
HttpResponse responsePOST = null;
int statusCode;
String data,fileName;
ImageView  downloadImg,shareImg;
TransparentProgressDialog pd;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;




private View previousItem;
public AuthorFragment(){}

public AuthorFragment(Context c)
{
    this.mContext=c;        
    bookGrid = (GridView)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.grid_view);   
    if(bookList!= null)
        bookList.clear();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(bookList!= null)
        bookList.clear();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shelf, container, false);
    mContext = rootView.getContext();
    bookGrid=(GridView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.grid_view);  
    pd = new TransparentProgressDialog(mContext, R.drawable.progress);
    pd.setCancelable(true);
    pd.show();


    // instantiate it within the onCreate method
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading book");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);




    bookGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {
            if (previousItem != null) {
                downloadImg=(ImageView) previousItem.findViewById(R.id.download);       
                shareImg=(ImageView) previousItem.findViewById(R.id.share);     
                downloadImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
                shareImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);       
            }
            downloadImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download);
            shareImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);
            downloadImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            shareImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            previousItem = view;


            downloadImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .toString();
                    File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Ebook");
                    folder.mkdir();
                    File folder1 = new File(folder, "books");
                    folder1.mkdir();                                
                    //File file = new File(folder1, bookList.get(position).bookConvertedFileName);
                    // DownloadFile(bookList.get(position).bookUrl, file);;
                    fileName =  bookList.get(position).bookConvertedFileName;
                    // execute this when the downloader must be fired
                    final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(mContext);
                    downloadTask.execute(bookList.get(position).bookUrl);

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });

    bookGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {     

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String userToken;
            AppUtils utils = new AppUtils(mContext);
            userToken = utils.getToken();
            if( userToken!= null &&  userToken!= "" )       {                   
                if(     check(bookList.get(position).bookConvertedFileName)==true)
                {
                    Intent i =new Intent (mContext,DetailedView.class);                 
                    Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
                    b1.putString("name",bookList.get(position).bookConvertedFileName);                  
                    i.putExtras(b1);                
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    showDialog("Give long press for downloading and share option");
                }
            }
            else {
                showDialog("Please login first");
            }


        }
    });

    bookThread bThread =new bookThread();
    bThread.start();        
    return rootView;
}
```

Please help me to find out the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem.In HomeFragment Instead of FragmentPagerAdapter, use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.The reason this works is because FragmentStatePagerAdapter destroys as Fragments that aren't being used. FragmentPagerAdapter does not.This below link saved me.
   [FragmentPagerAdapter getItem is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581896/fragmentpageradapter-getitem-is-not-called)